# "Не понятый другими" или "непонятый другими": причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: частица-не

В разных  текстах при наличии зависимых слов  встречается **как слитное, так и раздельное написание частицы НЕ**,   в словаре этому слову посвящена **специальная статья**. Так может ли причастие "непонятый" при определенных условиях перейти в прилагательное?

НЕПОНЯТЫЙ, Такой, который (которого) не поняли. Н-ое слово. Н. вопрос. Н. собеседник.

**Примеры**

1) В частности, для меня Блок стоит в ряду любимейших полулегендарных, а то и вовсе легендарных людей, таких, как  Петрарка...или **до сих пор не понятый** Лермонтов (К. Г. Паустовский,1955).

Вкус ― величайший и **еще не понятый** дар богов (Д. С. Мережковский. Смерть богов, 1895).

2) Гоголь умирал, **непонятый современниками** и потерявший надежду, что они его поймут (Сиповский В. История русской словесности).

...ей ужасно как хочется любить и блаженствовать; но кажется, что она **непонятый кем-нибудь** талант любви (А. Ф. Вельтман, 1848).

3) Не понимаю самого себя и просто боюсь быть **непонятым другими** (современные записи, "непонятый" в составе сказуемого).

Comment: *Так может ли причастие "непонятый" при определенных условиях перейти в прилагательное?* - насколько понимаю, вообще едва ли не любое причастие "при определенных обстоятельствах" "становится" отглагольным прилагательным. Но примеры из середины позапрошлого века и современного интернета одинаково непоказательны в плане орфографии. В первом случае она была другая, во втором - часто просто не соблюдается.

Answer (score 1):

"Непонятый другими" вполне может трактоваться как прилагательное. 
Только надо разницу между причастием и прилагательным рассматривать не на основании вторичных признаков-критериев уровня школьной орфограммы, а по сути. Причастие - состояние, прилагательное - качество. Всё.

Может "непонятый другими" быть качеством? Да запросто. Здесь "другими" просто избыточно в семантическом плане и *не годится в качестве влияющего на орфографию зависимого слова*. Это скорее всего именно *качество*, постоянный признак.

А вот "до сих пор" и "ещё" сразу придают "непонятому" характер меняющегося со временем *состояния*, поэтому и слитное написание в этих случаях как правило невозможно.

С другой стороны, согласен с тем, что общий подход к вопросу "причастие vs прилагательное" надо менять.

Если не углубляться в догматику, семантической разницы между прилагательным и причастиям почти нет. Грамматика в общем-то позволяет в большинстве случаев рассматривать одно как другое. Все же непростые правила - орфография ради орфографии, смысла в ней не более чем в ере в старой орфографии.

Аванесов еще в начале 80-х предлагал рассматривать причастие и отглагольное прилагательное как единую часть речи. А лопатинская Орфографическая комиссия рекомендовала избавиться хотя бы от ряда дифференцирующих написаний - в случаях, когда правила противоречивы и за ними не стоит семантических признаков. Но воз и ныне там.

Comment: Да, вы правы,  мне понятна необходимость различения зависимых слов, связанных о временем (еще, до сих пор и т.д.) от других  слов, которые могут пояснять качественное прилагательное и не должны влиять на орфографию (выбор Н или НН, слитное или раздельное написание НЕ). Но как обойти формальные школьные правила, слитное написание "непонятый другими" могут посчитать за ошибку.